Error: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
theme.xml​​
`
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="Theme._7MinutesWorkout" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolBarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.ActionBar">
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/toolbar_color_control_normal</item>
</style>

</resources>
`

activity_bmi.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main"
android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".BMIActivity">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar_bmi_activity"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/white" />

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/tilMetricUnitWeight"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:hint="Enter your value"
app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorAccent"
app:hintTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
style="@style/Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
android:id="@+id/etMetricUnitWeight"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="56dp"
android:padding="12dp"
android:hint="WEIGHT (in KG)"
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
android:textSize="16sp" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/tilMetricUnitHeight"
android:layout_below="@+id/tilMetricUnitWeight"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:hint="Enter your value"
app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorAccent"
app:hintTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
style="@style/Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
android:id="@+id/etMetricUnitHeight"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="56dp"
android:padding="12dp"
android:hint="HEIGHT (in CM)"
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
android:textSize="16sp" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/llDisplayBMIResult"
android:layout_below="@id/tilMetricUnitHeight"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
android:visibility="invisible"
tools:visibility="visible">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvYourBMI"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="YOUR BMI"
android:textAllCaps="true"
android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvBMIValue"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="15.00"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvBMIType"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="Normal"
android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvBMIDescription"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="Normal"
android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
android:id="@+id/btnCalculateUnits"
android:layout_below="@id/llDisplayBMIResult"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
android:text="CALCULATE"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textSize="18sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

AndroidMainfest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<queries>
<intent>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.TTS_SERVICE" />
</intent>
</queries>

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/Theme._7MinutesWorkout"
tools:targetApi="31">
<activity
android:name=".BMIActivity"
android:exported="false" />
<activity
android:name=".FinishActivity"
android:exported="false" />
<activity
android:name=".ExerciseActivity"
android:exported="false" />
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:exported="true"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/Theme._7MinutesWorkout">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>

Getting error:

Error inflating class
com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout This component
requires that you specify a valid TextAppearance attribute. Update
your app theme to inherit from Theme.MaterialComponents (or a
descendant).

I tried all stackoverflow answers but they don't work
